# pyTest: pre-test setup: fixtures vs hooks

Tags: pytest

I want to perform some actions before triggering the tests using pyTest. I see two options available for this task.

1. Using [session scoped fixtures](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html#scope-sharing-a-fixture-instance-across-tests-in-a-class-module-or-session) which can do the setup before all the tests start.
2. Using pyTest hooks e.g. [pytest_sessionstart](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionstart), [pytest_sessionfinish](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.hookspec.pytest_sessionfinish)

Which is the recommended method to use? Or in other words, which should be used when?

Comment: Usually, if you're in doubt whether to use fixtures or hooks, use fixtures. Hooks are for altering the framework itself, not for test related stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pytest hooks are to modify the behavior of pytest like modify the test collection strategy, test execution order etc. Fixtures are meant to set up the tests before they are executed, e.g. setting up db, initialize an app, etc.

It appears that you want to set up the test. You should go with fixture.